# Craft 3: Searching within back-end & front-end isn't giving all entries/results

Tags: craft3, control-panel, admin, frontend

Searching within Control Panel as well as the front-end is not going through all entries. When I try searching in the Content tab I see the pages are listed but when I try to search for the entry it won't give it as a result.

It seems to be only on entries that were created a long time ago.

It seems also that a re-save fixes the problem, but doing that for 10K+ entries is a pain. Hope you can help me to do something like Rebuild Search Indexes that was possible before 3.2.2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `craft resave/entries` console command and it will (among other things) update the search index table with the latest information for your entries.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! 

Is this also possible for Entries within a plugin like Calendar (https://docs.solspace.com/craft/calendar/v2/)? Because everything seems to be resaved but not the entries (activities) within this plugin.

Comment: Also manually saving such an event doesn't trigger updating the search index table. So therefore I have no way of fixing this here.